# Angularjs scope.safeapply() refresh

Tags: angularjs, cordova, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

My problem is:
I created a Cordova APP-s with AngularJS. This code is working but I have a little problem. The screen is refreshing when I tap on the screen. So there is no auto refresh. I tried $scope.apply() instead of $scope.safeApply() but did it not work. Even is there was data in the application_data table the data wasn't shown.

My controller:

```
$scope.datas = [];

db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM application_data', [], function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length, i;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
            $scope.id = results.rows.item(i).id;
            $scope.name = results.rows.item(i).name;
            $scope.date = results.rows.item(i).date;

            $scope.datas.push({id: $scope.id, name: $scope.name, date: $scope.date});

        }
    }, null);

    $scope.safeApply();
});
```

My view:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
    {{data.id}} - {{data.name}} - {{data.date}}
</div>
```

Comment: There should be an error, because it's $scope.$apply() not $scope.apply(). There's no such thing as $scope.safeApply() as well. If you defined it manually, the code should reflect it (and safe apply is also an antipattern).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put code inside of  $scope.$apply

```
$scope.datas = [];

db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM application_data', [], function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length, i;

        $scope.$apply(function() {

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                $scope.id = results.rows.item(i).id;
                $scope.name = results.rows.item(i).name;
                $scope.date = results.rows.item(i).date;

                $scope.datas.push({id: $scope.id, name: $scope.name, date: $scope.date});

            }
        });
    }, null);

});
```